# Regular expression replace with self

Tags: python, regex

I am using regular expressions to tag information in messages. These messages are structured in that certain pieces of information I am looking for are ordered. The order however for certain messages as well as the specific types of information I am looking for can change depending on the type of message. Below is a *minimal* example of such a message

```
message = 'foo 1234567890 bar'
```

Suppose I know my message to consist of 3 pieces of information I am looking for, `var_a`, `var_b`, and `var_c`. I know that `var_a` and `var_c` are lowercase strings while `var_b` is a number and that they appear in the order `var_a`, `var_b`, and then `var_c` in my message. I can tag them using

```
r = re.compile('(?P<var_a>[a-z]*)\s+(?P<var_b>[0-9]*)\s+(?P<var_c>[a-z]*)')
d = [m.groupdict() for m in r.finditer(message)][0]

for key, value in d.items():
    message = message.replace(value, f'[{key}]{value}[{key}]')
```

output

```
'[var_a]foo[var_a] [var_b]1234567890[var_b] [var_c]bar[var_c]'
```

However when I have duplicate words in my messages between for example `var_a` and `var_c`, i.e.

```
message = 'foo 1234567890 foo'
```

I get as ouput

```
'[var_a][var_c]foo[var_c][var_a] [var_b]1234567890[var_b] [var_a][var_c]foo[var_c][var_a]'
```

How would I go about dealing with this? I thought about immediately replacing the phrases during the regular expression matching (using something like re.sub) but I can't seem to figure out how to do this because I need to be able to reference both the names I'm using in my regular expression (like var_a etc.) as well as the content assigned to these names.

The output I would like to obtain is

```
'[var_a]foo[var_a] [var_b]1234567890[var_b] [var_c]foo[var_c]'
```

This includes the spaces (or for that matter any other kind of text from the original message).

Comment: What is the actual output you want here?

Comment: '[var_a]foo[var_a] [var_b]1234567890[var_b] [var_c]foo[var_c]'. This includes the spaces (or for that matter any other type of text in the original message that is not tagged).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with `re.sub` is probably more elegant, but you could also use the `groupdict` to get the `span` of the individual groups and then replace those (in reverse, as it alters the indices):

```
m = r.match(message)
msg = list(message)
for k, v in reversed(list(m.groupdict().items())):
    s, e = m.span(k)
    msg[s:e] = list(f"[{k}]{v}[{k}]")

print(''.join(msg))
# '[var_a]foo[var_a] [var_b]1234567890[var_b] [var_c]foo[var_c]'
```

Or, if those groups are always only separated by spaces (and it is okay to replace more spaces with a single space in the output), you could also simply `join` the items in the `groupdict` (order should be as matched).

```
print(" ".join(f"[{k}]{v}[{k}]" for k, v in m.groupdict().items()))
```

Comment: I think you are correct that the answer using re.sub by Tim is more elegant. But I have accepted this answer as the correct one as it gives control over the variables k and v, say, that I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `re.sub` here as:

```
message = 'foo 1234567890 bar'
output = re.sub(r'\b([a-z]+) (\d+) ([a-z]+)\b', '[var_a]\\1[var_a] [var_b]\\2[var_b] [var_c]\\3[var_c]', message)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
[var_a]foo[var_a] [var_b]1234567890[var_b] [var_c]bar[var_c]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use f-strings here?

Comment: See the answer by @tobias_k for that approach.